# Xcode Entity Core Data - NSDate wrong year?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

When storing values to core data, the Date is stored as a TimeStamp but the year is incorrect. How can I sore the correct datetime to core storage?

### Steps taken

Using Xcode and Swift I have created an iPhone project and added an Entity with the following attributes:

```
Attribute    Type
-------------------
name         String
date         Date
```

I am using core data to save data entries. eg:

```
 myEntity = MyEntity(context: self.viewContext)  
 myEntity.name = nameString
 myEntity.date = Date() as NSDate
 self.appDelegate.saveContext()
```

This creates records on the phone in a sqlite database. When I open the Sqlite database on the phone, I can see the records created as follows:

```
Z_PK    Z_NAME    Z_DATE
1       George    521035200
```

Converting the Date value using the following command:

```
SELECT datetime(521035200, 'unixepoch');

OUTPUTS: 1986-07-06 12:00:00
```

The day/month is correct but the year should be 2017.

What is the correct format of the timestamp in SQLite?

Is it possible to store a date using Xcode Entity instead of a time stamp?

Comment: CoreData stores dates with a different epoch. It's not the standard Unix epoch of 1/1/1970.

Comment: Yes it seems to store them with a different offset - when converting values back using the entity the date is correct.

Comment: See the documentation for `Date` (`NSDate`) for details about the epoch used.

Comment: The NSDate reference date is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001. Which is drawn from the OS X launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data considers the layout of its SQLite file to be a private implementation detail. Although it's clearly valid to open and inspect the file to debug and to profile, you shouldn't plan to do that systematically as part of your application or a wider data flow. If you do then you're coupling yourself to a private implementation detail, so you should expect your code to break arbitrarily and without recourse.

That being said, the `NSDate` reference date [is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate) so if you're a human being trying to inspect some data for verification, you're quite possibly looking at an offset from that.

You could store a time stamp as something other than an `NSDate` but there'd be no benefit to doing so as it wouldn't resolve your coupling to non-guaranteed structure, and it'd make your use of Core Data uglier.

Comment: Was just trying to create some dummy data in the database for testing the the date threw me. Thanks for explanation.